# Format output of python numpy array, no [ ] or ' '

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to python and with numpy module. I have 2 arrays, dtype=str, and I want them to print as 2 columns. I can currently get both arrays to print together:

`[ 'Bob' 'Bobby' ...][ 'Dave' 'David' ...]` (with several columns in the array and I want each array to be 1 column)

But I want them to print like this:

```
Bob Dave
Bobby David
... ...
```

with no [  ] or ' ' in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make 2 arrays (adapted from your display - but a simple copy-n-paste would be nicer):

```
In [63]: arr1 = np.array([ 'Bob', 'Bobby', '...'])
    ...: arr2 = np.array([ 'Dave', 'David', '...'])
In [64]: arr1
Out[64]: array(['Bob', 'Bobby', '...'], dtype='<U5')
In [65]: arr2
Out[65]: array(['Dave', 'David', '...'], dtype='<U5')
```

One common way to join 2 1d arrays:

```
In [66]: np.vstack((arr1,arr2))
Out[66]: 
array([['Bob', 'Bobby', '...'],
       ['Dave', 'David', '...']], dtype='<U5')
```

this can be transposed to form the 'columns' you want:

```
In [67]: _.T
Out[67]: 
array([['Bob', 'Dave'],
       ['Bobby', 'David'],
       ['...', '...']], dtype='<U5')
```

another way:

```
In [68]: np.stack((arr1,arr2), axis=1)
Out[68]: 
array([['Bob', 'Dave'],
       ['Bobby', 'David'],
       ['...', '...']], dtype='<U5')
```

Such a 2d array display is what you want, but I think it's more important to understand the underlying data structure, than to get formatting details right.

But the easiest way to format such an array without quotes and [] is use the function designed to write `csv` files:

```
In [69]: np.savetxt('test.txt', _, fmt='%10s')
In [70]: cat test.txt
       Bob       Dave
     Bobby      David
       ...        ...
```

This function is rather simple, iterating on rows of the array, and formatting the row.  It might be a good exercise in using the basic Python string formatting that you must have studied in intro Python!

Or treating the arrays as lists, simply iteration and print:

```
In [71]: for a, b in zip(arr1,arr2):
    ...:     print(a,b)
    ...: 
Bob Dave
Bobby David
... ...
```

You see, this isn't much of a `numpy` task; it's better with lists of strings.

Or with `pandas`:

```
In [72]: pd.DataFrame(Out[67])
Out[72]: 
       0      1
0    Bob   Dave
1  Bobby  David
2    ...    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use Array Iteration and get value than create one string and print.